# Toolbar theme not applied from styles (22.1.0)

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Prior to appcompat version 22.1.0, I was able to define a global style for my apps toolbars in styles.xml.

```
<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.Toolbar</item>
```

My global toolbar style declared a theme attribute for the toolbar:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Widget.Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
       <item name="theme">@style/AppTheme.Widget.Toolbar.ThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

After upgrading to 22.1.0 and changing the **theme** attribute to the new **android:theme** attribute, the theme no longer gets applied. If I declare this theme on a toolbar in  a layout.xml, it works.

How can I declare a global theme for toolbars with a global style?

Comment: @chris-banes would love your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug, as `android:theme` has greater meaning over any style (styles get their values from themes).

This did work in previous versions as a side effect of the implementation. The implementation is now much closer to how `LayoutInflater` works in Android 5.0+.

Comment: Right. So there is no way to make a toolbar use a dark theme (with the app theme set to Light), using only global styles?